# Firebase App Tester Not Recognizing Tablet as Mobile Device

Tags: firebase

I used to be able to use apptester no problem but now I get this error when using my samsung tablet to open the invite email from outlook.

[error message screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e7hUP.jpg)

I tried updating the OS, I am in developer mode, I'm logged in to the device with the email associated with the invitation.

Answer (score 0):

Try in another browser like Google Chrome.
I had the same problem so I tried in Chrome and it did let me install the app.